# Jenkins pipeline how to change to another folder

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

Currently  i am using Jenkins pipeline script.

For running one command, I need to access a folder outside its workspace directory.

I tried `sh "cd $workspace/"`, but it returned current workspace folder.

How I can change to root workspace directory and then cd to another folder. Please help.

Answer (score 256):

You can use the [`dir`](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-durable-task-step/#dir-change-current-directory) step, example:

```
dir("folder") {
    sh "pwd"
}
```

The `folder` can be relative or absolute path.

Comment: but it will go inside that current job folder. I want to switch to jenkins workspace

Comment: how do you go back upwards?

Comment: @DanDan everything outside this `dir` step is 'back upwards', see also answer/example from Gonzalo Robert Diaz: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59776342/757308

Comment: Be aware that outside the dir the directory is resetted. It is not like `cd directory` in a shell.

Comment: When I try and run sh 'git add .' inside the "folder", it throws me this error: + git add .
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git

Comment: can I do it for all future stage ?

Answer (score 63):

The `dir` wrapper can wrap, any other step, and it all works inside a `steps` block, for example:

```
steps {
    sh "pwd"
    dir('your-sub-directory') {
      sh "pwd"
    }
    sh "pwd"
}
```

Comment: what is an expected output ?

Answer (score 38):

Use WORKSPACE environment variable to change workspace directory.

If doing using Jenkinsfile, use following code :

```
dir("${env.WORKSPACE}/aQA"){
    sh "pwd"
}
```

Comment: `dir('aQA')` works the same way. No need for that complexity

Comment: What if you want to make sure to run the command in the root directory of the workspace?