# How to switch from one directory to another directory in groovy

Tags: groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

1) I have cloned a bitbucket repo name `myrepo` which has 5 folders..branch name is development.

2) In all 5 folders (`A`,`B`,`C`,`D`,`E`) I need to view `A` folder contents using jenkins pipeline so that the user will have choice to pick/select.

3) All files names should be shown as `xxx` only not as `xxx_yar.yaml`.

I have implemented one func which clones bitbucket repo and executing shell command to find `A` dir and removing `_yar.yaml` and getting output as `xxx`.

Here the problem is I am not able to switch from `myrepo` folder to `A` folder to execute shell command:

```
 def CREDS="xxxxxx"
 static void clonerepo(CREDS) {
     def git branch: "development",
             credentialsId: "${CREDS}",
             url: "https://bitbucket.com/xxx/xx/myrepo.git"
     sh(find A -type f -maxdepth 1 | cut -d "/" -f 2 | sed -e "s/_yar.yaml//g")
 }
```

After this in pipeline question I have given in below format

```
  MYNAME=input( id: 'userInput', message: 'What is the application?', parameters: [ [$class: 'ChoiceParameterDefinition', choices: clonerepo, description: '', name: ''] ])
```

so that in above choices all `A` files contents will be shown to user.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jenkins pipeline how to change to another folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52372589/jenkins-pipeline-how-to-change-to-another-folder)

Comment: @MostafaHussein will this work? 

dir("myrepo/A") {
    sh "pwd"
}

Above sh command i need to place or what?

Comment: Yes it will work, `dir` takes a parameter which should be the directory you need to move into it, then you can execute commands inside this directory like using `sh`